# getElementsByClassName in Powr Social Stream

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname, velo

I use Powr Social Stream on Wix. It agregates social streams onto a web site. The component offers the possibility to add Jscript. 
Inside the components generated html is the following (many times repeating) block, the footer that displays the date of a FaceBook posting:

```
<div class="postDate fitText fitTextNoWrap" style="font-size: 10px;">
                    Fri Nov 24 2017
                  </div>
```

I want to change the date format into DD/MM/YYYY so I thought I would get all elements of that class using this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("postDate");
var i;
console.log("# elements=") + x.length;
```

But x.lenght comes up empty. Console does print the "# elements =" (twice actually). Does anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thank you for any help you can give me.

BTW If you wonder why I don´t ask Powr: they don´t support Javacript questions.

Comment: `console.log("# elements=" + x.length);`

Comment: Thank you, Chris, but now it comes up with "0". Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure the code runs *after* the HTML is loaded: https://jsfiddle.net/g3796dnx/